# swift 'UIImage?' is not convertible to 'UIImage'

Tags: swift, xcode

I am getting the error 'UIImage?' is not convertible to 'UIImage' 
for the line `let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage`
 in my image picker function (below)

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage

    // how do i set the image on my buttons when I select a photo?
    let imageButton = (picker as? CustomImagePickerController)?.imageButton
    imageButton?.setImage(selectedImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    dismiss(animated: true)

    let filename = UUID().uuidString
    let ref = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "/images/\(filename)")
    guard let uploadData = selectedImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75) else { return }


    //guard let uploadData = selectedImage else { return }

    let hud = JGProgressHUD(style: .dark)
    hud.textLabel.text = "Uploading image..."
    hud.show(in: view)
    ref.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (nil, err) in
        if let err = err {
            hud.dismiss()
            print("Failed to upload image to storage:", err)
            return
        }

        print("Finished uploading image")
        ref.downloadURL(completion: { (url, err) in

            hud.dismiss()

            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to retrieve download URL:", err)
                return
            }

            print("Finished getting download url:", url?.absoluteString ?? "")

            if imageButton == self.image1Button {
                self.user?.imageUrl1 = url?.absoluteString
            } else if imageButton == self.image2Button {
                self.user?.imageUrl2 = url?.absoluteString
            } else {
                self.user?.imageUrl3 = url?.absoluteString
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ran into the same error - next to the unwrapping of the `selectedImage`, make sure you have the correct/updated function parameters (they changed the `info` from type `[String : Any]` to `[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]` which was giving me the error.

This is how it should look like:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
        print("Error: \(info)")
        return
    }

    // do your thing...

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

The signature of:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
```

has been changed to:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
```

which is the cause of error.

Changing the signature to the new one, i.e:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
```

will resolve the error.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
guard let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else { return }
```

Answer (score 0):

info is changed in `info: [String : Any]` (thanks apple to change every time)

override your func in the new one:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
```

Answer (score -2):

That's because you need to unwrap `selectedImage` first:

```
guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else { return }
```

Comment: Did you remove the optional question marks on `selectedImage` after unwrapping?

Comment: yes i still get 'UIImage?' is not convertible to 'UIImage'

Comment: im also getting a warning Cast from 'Slice<Dictionary<UIImagePickerController.InfoKey, Any>>' (aka 'Slice<Dictionary<NSString, Any>>') to unrelated type 'UIImage' always fails

Comment: So your problem is that you are trying to convert something that is not an `UIImage` to the `UIImage` type.

Comment: thanks Vasil That appears to be what xcode is telling me though how do I fix it?

Comment: Version 10.1 (10B61)